# Sequences of functions that converge uniformly, or pointwise, but not in $L^1.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading the book Real Analysis of Folland. When I reached chapter 2 about the different modes of convergence, there's an example Folland gave that confused me:

> > The 2 function sequences:
> >     
> > i) $f_n = \chi_{(n, n+1)}$
> >     
> > ii) $f_n = n\chi_{[0, 1/n]}$
> >     
> > uniformly, pointwise converge to $0$, but not converge in $L^1$

I can easily point out that those 2 functions pointwise converge to $0$ as well as not converge in $L^1$. But I don't think those 2 functions uniformly converge. Like the first case, for all $N$ and choose $\epsilon < 1$, we can always choose $x \in (N , N+1)$, then $|f_n(x)| = 1 > \epsilon$. Did I miss some points? (The example is in chapter 2, page 61) Please help me to judge this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood what he says. Folland writes:

> (i) $f_n=n^{-1}\chi_{(0,n)}$
>
> (ii) $f_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$
>
> (iii) $f_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$
>
> In (i), (ii), and (iii), $f_n\to 0$ converges uniformly, pointwise, and a.e. *respectively*.

So $f_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$ does not converge uniformly, but pointwise which is evident. Only the first one converges uniformly.

Comment: Ah yeah, so it means the first case converges uniformly, the second pointwise and the last a.e, right. Thanks so much for clarifying.